# How to make a route in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-router, url-routing, screen

The routers Is not working, I tryed many forms but not worked, can someone help me?

the following error is: Device: (487:41) undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

```
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Noturno from './containerNoturno.js';
import Linhas from './Linhas.js';
import LSaida from './LinhasSaida.js';
import Main from './containerDiurno.js';
import Ajuda from './Ajuda.js';
import Sobre from './sobre.js';
import Intro from './intro.js';
import GalopolisSantaCoronaNoturno from './Noturno/GalopolisSantaCorona.js';

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
Menu: { screen: Main },
Noturno: { screen: Noturno },
Linhas: { screen: Linhas },
Linhas_Saida: { screen: LSaida },
Ajuda: { screen: Ajuda },
Sobre: { screen: Sobre },
Galopolis_Noturno: { screen: GalopolisSantaCoronaNoturno },
});
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

here is the other code:

```
  <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Noturno')}
      style={styles.fab}>
      <Image
        source={require('../assets/noite.png')}
        style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Please open the follow link and help me...

Comment: Could you tell me in which file does this error happen? What is the screen you are currently in when you press something to trigger this.props.navigation.navigate?

Comment: i`m in the Diurno.js screen, and Itryed to go to the Noturno.js screen with the follow command:   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Noturno')}, but it not worked.. :/

Comment: And where is your router?

Comment: in the Menu.js screen

Comment: I think it should be createDrawerNavigator instead of DrawerNavigator

Comment: Change it in both import and in your const Navegador

Comment: not work yet.. I will put here the codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the navigation prop in child component "Noturno.js" which is not part of StackNavigator

You can access the prop like this ([Access the navigation prop from any component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html))

**Update file "Noturno.js"**

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

....

class App extends React.Component

....


export default withNavigation(App);
```

Comment: Hi, how can I access a props (component) from a master component? there is away?